# javascript function to show current time as pre-selected value of html select tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have two select tags in html, one for hour and one for minutes. I want the default value of hour to be set on current hour and the value of minute to be set on current minute. I think with default time to be set for example on 3, i should have some thing like this:

```
<select name="hour">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
...
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

now my question is how can i use javascript to show the current hour and minutes by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you're creating the `option` elements, one approach is to use:

```
var now = new Date(),
    // we're adding one because JavaScript returns zero-based hours, 0-23
    hour = now.getUTCHours() + 1,
    sel = document.getElementById('hours'),
    opt;

for (var i=0; i<24; i++){
    opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.textContent = i;
    sel.appendChild(opt);
    if (i == hour) {
        opt.selected = true;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2dgfr/).

This uses the JavaScript `Date()` methods, `getUTCHours()`

If your `option` elements are already set in the HTML, and you're simply changing which is `selected` by default:

```
var now = new Date(),
    hour = now.getUTCHours() + 1,
    sel = document.getElementById('hours'),
    curHour = sel.getElementsByTagName('option')[hour];

curHour.selected = true;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2dgfr/1/).

References:

- [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Why `getUTCHours()` rather than `getHours()`? I know the OP didn't make it clear, but if I had to guess I'd say the local time would be more useful for the user.

Comment: Mainly because, while I was writing that answer, your own answer popped up. So I figured I'd post an alternative hour-getting method, rather than, essentially, repeating yours.

Comment: I use your code with getHours() function rather than getUTCHours() to show my system time. really useful specially for auto-generate options.thank you :)

Comment: I forgot to say before, I don't think you need to add 1 to the hours: yes, in JS they're zero-based, but so too are real-world hours.

Comment: If you visit the JS Fiddles, and remove the `+ 1` then they don't seem to work properly any more, though?

Answer (score 1):

There are JavaScript [`Date` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) called [`.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) and [`.getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes). So given:

```
<select id="hour" name="hour">...</select>
<select id="minute" name="minute">...</select>
```

You can do something like the following in a script block that appears after the selects (or is called onload or on DOM ready):

```
var currentDateTime = new Date();

document.getElementById("hour").value = currentDateTime.getHours();
document.getElementById("minute").value = currentDateTime.getMinutes();
```